# Running SageMaker ProcessingJob as non root user

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, unix, amazon-sagemaker, user-permissions

Files copied by SageMaker from s3 to docker inside ProcessingJob have root ownership and permissions which do not allow non owner users (non root) to write to them.

I'd like to run the docker container as non root user and be able to write to folders created by SageMaker, so the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM base

...

USER nonroot
```

Exemplary permissions and ownership of folders copied from s3 to SageMaker's docker container:

```
2022-11-30T10:20:13.567+01:00   + ls -la /opt/ml/processing

2022-11-30T10:20:13.567+01:00   total 24

2022-11-30T10:20:13.567+01:00   drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Nov 30 09:20 .

2022-11-30T10:20:13.567+01:00   drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 30 09:20 ..

2022-11-30T10:20:13.567+01:00   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 30 09:20 data

2022-11-30T10:20:13.568+01:00   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 30 09:20 output
```

I'd expect these folders to either has `nonroot` user ownership.

I've checked the documentation but no luck there. If there's any obvious way to achieve this that I missed, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: SageMaker Processing run the container in root mode only.
Why are you trying to tun the container as a non-root user?